# What is the best way to uninstall graphdb-free 9.3.0 on Linux?

Tags: graphdb

I have just downloaded GraphDB Desktop (v10.0), the replacement for GraphDB Free (I have v9.3.0). The installation notes say that I have to stop GraphDB Free and uninstall it before installing the new version. Understandable, but there is no information on **how** to uninstall the application. Can anyone point me to the relevant information?

Comment: While this may be on topic here, do consider using [unix.se], or - particularly if using Ubuntu - [AskUbuntu](https://www.askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove graphdb-free
```